# Can the decimal be increased for values come from summary?

Tags: r

The mean of all data I have is 0.2.I want to have more decimals otherwise it is meaningless if I want to compare between two files.
Example

```
   summary(f)
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 0.0     0.1     0.2     0.2     0.2     0.7  824982
```

so the mean here can be 0.29 or 0.21.Any idea on how to know this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
options(digits=10)
summary(f)
```

From `?options`

> ‘digits’: controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values.  It is a suggestion only.  Valid values are 1...22 with default 7.  See the note in ‘print.default’ about values greater than 15.

Note that the number of digits that is printed is different than the number of digits that is stored internally.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `digits` argument :

```
R> summary(rnorm(10))
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# -1.5520 -0.1925  0.2027  0.1862  0.8423  1.5470 
R> summary(rnorm(10),digits=10)
#       Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
# -2.2444487 -1.2681605  0.1552090 -0.2980934  0.4828649  1.3489778
```

Comment: +1 you beat me by seconds! and I prefer this solution of local settings!

Comment: @juba, but GSee gave you +1 because this is a good answer to the specific problem. ;)

Comment: @GSee Well, I gave you +1 too because your answer was a good way to generalize the desired behaviour and to learn how to customize R a bit :)